# How do we create a new file with new name from terminal in visual studio code?

Tags: c#, .net, terminal

yeah, I mean, in the video instructions I got from youtube, to create a new file through VSC terminal, we do like this :

**dotnet new**

It will then create a default helloworld.csproj file. But how do we make a new one with different name? I try this :

**dotnet new name -program2**

but it won't work.

Can anybody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It seems the below documentation link is incorrect or out of date. The latest version of the dotnet CLI doesn't seem to support `--name` or `-n`. However, the project name is generated from the current directory. Thus, you can write:

```
mkdir programname && cd programname && dotnet new
```

---

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new), `name` is a flag, not an argument. Thus, you should be writing:

```
dotnet new --name program2
```

Or for short:

```
dotnet new -n program2
```

Comment: it still can't bro. Here i show you what i've tried :

PS E:\Tobat Pemrograman\projectStars> dotnet new -n programstars2
Template Instantiation Commands for .NET Core CLI.

Usage: dotnet new [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  template  The template to instantiate.